# PDF links getting stuck while loading in Chrome PDF Viewer

Tags: html, django, google-chrome, anchor, httpresponse

On a page of a website we're building http://ovsd.nutrislice.com/wellness/ , pdf download links ("Download the Issue") get stuck while loading in Chrome's PDF Viewer but work in all other browsers by triggering a download. Right click + "Save as" works in Chrome. I realize Chrome is the only browser with a built-in, default pdf viewer.

I figure we can instruct people to right click and then "save as", but I wanted to see if anyone can see a problem with either the html, or in the server response, which would cause chrome to fail like that.

Its not a traditional pass-thru file download sitting on a server somewhere.  We use Heroku, and I'm currently storing the pdf's in the DB (I realize the downsides of this, but it was a simpler system than managing off-site files on S3 for now). I'm generating the response dynamically via a Django View, so I wonder if there's something i'm missing in the response headers or something.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like a bad content-type:

```
Content-Type:('application/pdf', None)
```

Check your code where you are assigning a content-type to the response. Looks like you're sending a tuple instead of just `application/pdf`.

Comment: Thanks for the find! You nailed it.  I was inappropriately setting the entire return value (which is a tuple) from the mimetypes.guess_type method as the content_type. http://docs.python.org/2/library/mimetypes.html#mimetypes.guess_type

Answer (score 3):

Like @dgel mentioned, your content type is incorrect:

```
$ curl -I http://ovsd.nutrislice.com/dbfiles/cms/resources/Vol5_Issue1_5_Dos_and_Donts_for_Supermarket_Survival.pdf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST,GET,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: max-age=90000
Content-Type: ('application/pdf', None)       # <- Incorrect
Date: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 19:25:06 GMT
Expires: Fri, 09 Nov 2012 23:20:28 GMT
Last-Modified: Thu, 08 Nov 2012 22:20:28 GMT
Server: gunicorn/0.14.6
Connection: keep-alive
```

Also it might be a good idea to add `Content-Length` header.

Comment: Good tip on content-length.  Interesting discussion of content-length header here: http://tech.hickorywind.org/articles/2008/05/23/content-length-mostly-does-not-matter-the-reverse-bob-barker-rule  I'm adding it to my list of things to do since it would be easy to set.